# MacOS Mojave - remove PHP installation from php-osx.liip.ch

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, php, mamp

I followed this tutorial https://php-osx.liip.ch/ and installed the php 7.3 version on MacOSX Mojave, running

```
curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.3
```

But now I changed my mind and I want remove it and return to a clean status; what are the steps I should follow to remove every trace of it? Thank you!

(Sorry it is a repost from Stackoverflow)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer by DavidPostill, and what I have found on Time Machine,this would be my course of action

`/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` is the same, so I'll keep it untouched

`/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf` > remove

```
usr/local/php5
usr/local/php5-7.3.8-20190811-205217
```

remove them

`.profile` on my user's folder: remove the line `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH`

`usr/local/packager` > I think it can be removed

What do you think?

Comment: I want to do the same thing as well.  Did you end up removing `/usr/local/packager` as well?

Comment: @Keven indeed, yes I did.

Answer (score -1):

#### What are the steps I should follow to remove every trace of it?

> **Uninstall**
>
> Change in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`
>
> ```
> LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
> ```
>
> Also delete the file `+php-osx.conf` and `+entropy-php.conf` in
>   `/etc/apache2/other` and optionally remove `/usr/local/php5-*`

Source [PHP for OS X / macOS as binary package](https://php-osx.liip.ch/#uninstall)

Comment: Thank you for your answer;
1) /etc/apache2/httpd.conf contains only a commented line `#LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so`
2) /etc/apache2/other contains
- a symlink +php-osx.conf >>> /usr/local/php5/entropy-php.conf
3) /etc/php5 is a symlink >>> /usr/local/php5-7.3.8-20190811-205217
4) usr/local/ contains also a /packager/ folder - can it be deleted?

Comment: Sorry, no idea :(